# How to give access to localhost:8080 on network?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, localhost, glassfish-4

How to make my computer as a server so I run the application on IDE and be accessible by other computers on same network via their browsers?

Comment: by changing localhost with your IP address. but i dont think its easy as that. can you elaborate your question?

Comment: what else do you need to know please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server local ip for example is 192.168.1.20 and your web server port is 8080 then you can access your server by giving IP:PORT in the browser
eg: 192.168.1.20:8080/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You can't make "localhost" accessible, by definition. What you can do instead is have the server process listen on an external IP address (or all addresses) instead of just on the loopback address. We can provide a more specific answer if you'll tell us how you're launching the application server.

Comment: I am launching it locally, I've just added Glassfish as a Netbean's server and run the application.